# Can't unzip .zip files in Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Tags: xubuntu, zip

I downloaded some .zip files and tried three different programs to open them and these are the results that I got:

Squeeze: command exited with status 2304

Archive Manager: cannot open file as archive

Xarchiver: Archive format is not recognized

So, how am I supposed to open .zip files?

Comment: Are you sure the files are not corrupted? or maybe they are not really a zip file? you could check them in a terminal with `file yourzipfile.zip`

Answer (score 1):

go to the command line `ctrl` + `alt` + `t`, `cd` to the directory the file is contained in like so:

`cd /path/to/dir`

Then use the `unzip` command to extract the file into the current directory:

`unzip file.zip`

You can also unzip a file into a directory of choice by using the '-d' flag:

`unzip file.zip -d /path/to/dir`

I believe unzip comes pre-installed on 12.04 but if not type the following command into the terminal to install:

`sudo apt-get install unzip`

Hope this helps and let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Even using unzip in the command line wasn't opening the files. I suspect flareget was somehow corrupting or not downloading the files right. As soon as I ditched flareget and installed downthemall I have had no problems with downloading and opening .zip files now.